# How to create PDO connection in __construct()?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have one class that is containing three methods. All of those methods need to database, Then I want to create a system for connection to database before everything. Something like this:

```
Class myclass
{
    private $db;

    public function __construct() {

        $db = new PDO("mysql:host = hostname; dbname = database",username, password);
    }

    function one()   {/* it needs to database and I will use it like this: */
                         $this->$db->prepare("select ...");
                     }
    function two()   {/* also it needs to database */}
    function three() {/* also it needs to database */}
}
```

Now I want to know (in first) what I did is a standard approach? and (in second) how can I check [if connection was disconnect (in other word connection does not exist) then connect] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access class properties, you have to use `->` syntax:

```
Class myclass
{
    private $db;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host = hostname; dbname = database",username, password);
    }

    function one()   {/* it needs to database and I will use it like this: */
        $this->db->prepare("select ...");
    }
    function two()   {/* also it needs to database */}
    function three() {/* also it needs to database */}
}
```

If you want to detect errors, enable error signalling with

```
$this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

and use `try/catch` around the code that uses the DB:

```
function one() {
    try {
        $this->db->prepare(...);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not what the OP asked.

Comment: I think we need to check if it is disconnected then connect, is it not? `if(self::$db == null){ // connect }`

Comment: It's not a static property, it's a per-object property. So it will never be connected when the constructor is called.

Comment: Is it not better to I define `$db` as `static`? because in this case, it will be defined just one time. what is the standard approach? `private $db;` or `private static $db;`

Comment: It seems like most people make it a singleton class, so they use a static property. But that means you can't have multiple database connections if you need it, so it's not as flexible.

Comment: thanks for the answer and for the question too! that's what I was looking for to better understand pdo inside a class definition. Thanks

Comment: `$this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Answer (score 1):

2 possible approaches:

**1.:** extend the PDO class (you will also inherit all the public methods)

this is my personal favorite.

```
Class myclass extends PDO
{
    //constructor is inherited from PDO so you dont need to create a new one

    function one()   {/* it needs to database and I will use it like this: */
                         //access internal methods via $this:
                         $this->prepare("select ...");
                     }
    function two()   {/* also it needs to database */}
    function three() {/* also it needs to database */}
}
```

trying to establish a connection:

```
try{
    $db = new myclass("mysql:host = hostname; dbname = database","useer", "asdf");
}
 catch (PDOException $e) {
   print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>".PHP_EOL;
   exit("ERROR OCCURED");
}
```

**2.** create pdo object as a property

Class myclass2
{
    private $db;

```
public function __construct() {

    try{
            $this->db = new myclass("mysql:host = hostname; dbname = database","useer", "asdf");
            }
             catch (PDOException $e) {
               print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>".PHP_EOL;
               exit("ERROR OCCURED");
            }
    }

function one()   {/* it needs to database and I will use it like this: */
                     $this->db->prepare("select ...");
                 }
function two()   {/* also it needs to database */}
function three() {/* also it needs to database */}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Create class db

```
class db {

/*** Declare instance ***/
private static $instance = NULL;

/**
*
* the constructor is set to private so
* so nobody can create a new instance using new
*
*/
private function __construct() {
  /*** maybe set the db name here later ***/
}

/**
*
* Return DB instance or create intitial connection
*
* @return object (PDO)
*
* @access public
*
*/
public static function getInstance() {
    if (!self::$instance) {
        self::$instance = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOSTNAME.";dbname=".DB_DATABASE, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
        self::$instance-> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);
    }

    return self::$instance;
}

public static function close() {
    if (self::$instance) {
        self::$instance = null;
    }
}

/**
*
* Like the constructor, we make __clone private
* so nobody can clone the instance
*
*/
private function __clone(){
}

} /*** end of class ***/
```

To use it:

```
DB::getInstance()
```

Wow, poor answer. OK :)

To me seems the best way. Just create a class, and when you need it call a instance of that.

Comment: Poor answer, you didn't answer the questions.